# How to initialize char array with numerical symbols from int values?

Tags: c++, char, arguments, int

I want to load some sounds, and loading function wants

```
const char*
```

as an argument. So I do

```
const char name1[]="audio/audioname_1.wav";
LoadAudio(name1);
```

and pass it as an argument. But there is

```
const char name2[]="audio/audioname_2.wav";
const char name3[]="audio/audioname_3.wav";
```

...

So I want something like:

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) LoadAudio("audio/audioname_"+i.ToChar()+".wav");
```

Or i dont know, just want minimum lines of code here)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: Since this is C++, you use use `std::string`. It makes concatenation easier

Comment: But those are strings, I want char. I dont understand that stuff much, can someone just give quick example, please.

Comment: Read more about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), there are ways to get a `const char*` from a `std::string`. Besides using `to_string` with concatenation, you could also use an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to format the string. You should learn about the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), what it contains and what it can do. It will help you enormously in the future as a C++ programmer.

Comment: Reading, its not helping

Comment: You expect us to just write the code for you without you putting any effort into it at all?

Comment: See strcat if you are very strict to use char* http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Comment: @QuizCanners Hint: what does the string's member function `c_str()` do?

Comment: std::stringstream text;
text<<"audio/step/grass_dry_hit_soft-00"<<i<<"wav";  How do I use this as an arguments?

Comment: There is a function in `std::istringstream` to get the underlying `std::string`, and from a `std::string` there is a function to get a `const char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who suggested you learning about std::string are right. But if you want an "right now" answer, try this

```
char soundName[MAX_NAME_SIZE] = {};

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SOUND_FILES; i++)
{
    sprintf   (soundName, "audio/audioname_%d.wav", i);
    LoadAudio (soundName);
}
```

Where SOUND_FILES constant is how many sound files you have, and MAX_NAME_SIZE constant is maximum for amount of characters in name of file.